# How to overlay/overlap two div's designed with css to look like text bubbles?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overlay, css-position, margin

**My main problem is how can I get the foreground bubble (in blue) to be slightly below and to the right of the background bubble under all conditions?**

I've tried playing around with different ways of overlapping objects on top of each other... specifically using the following ways:

1. Playing around with negative margins
2. Absolute/Relative positioning and z-index

However, I'm not able to get one combination which works under "all conditions" and keeps the text bubble "whole." (see note below)

Specifically, the conditions I'm facing are:

1. **Different Text Lengths** --- The text which currently written in as "Some Title" is automatically generated and could very in size (i.e. number of characters) so the bubbles need to adjust to be a different number of lines (1-5).
2. **Differing Browser Sizes** --- I want the text bubbles to adjust in response to the size of the browser, but not the distance between them.

Also note:

- I'm using the latest version of Twitter Bootstrap.
- I use specific before/after psuedo elements on the text bubbles so their little tips are placed in what appears to be okay location aesthetically. These would often get screwed up when I tried the second method above to solve the problem.

Bonus points if you can make the tips on the text bubbles look better ;)

Here's my html:

```
           <div>
              <div id="head-names">
                <h2>
                  Person A
                </h2>
                <h2>
                  Person B
                </h2>
              </div>
              <div align="center">
                    <h2 class="text-bubble background-bubble">
                      <p>Some Title</p>
                     </h2>
                    <h2 class="text-bubble foreground-bubble">
                      <p>Some Title</p>
                    </h2>
              </div>
          </div>
```

And my css:

```
           #head-names {
                display:flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-around;
                flex-wrap:wrap;
            }

            .text-bubble {
                position:relative;
                text-align : center;    
                border-radius:30px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
                -moz-border-radius: 30px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
                -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
                box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
                max-width:650px;
                padding: 10px 20px;
                margin: 0 0 20px;
            }


            .text-bubble:before {
                content:"";
                position:absolute;
                width: 0;
                height:0;    
                border-style:solid;
            }


            .text-bubble:after {
                content:"";
                position:absolute;
                border-style:solid;    
                display:block;
                width: 0;
            }

            .foreground-bubble {
                background-color: #ADD8E6;
                border: 6px solid #666;
                left:2%;   
            }

            .foreground-bubble:before {
                bottom:100%;
                left:13%;
                border-color: transparent transparent #666 #666;
                border-width: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
            }


            .foreground-bubble:after {
                bottom:100%;
                left:15%;
                border-color: transparent transparent #ADD8E6 #ADD8E6;
                border-width: 18px 18px 18px 18px;    
            }

            .background-bubble {
                background-color: #fff;
                border: 6px solid #666;
                left:-2%;
                color:transparent;
                margin-bottom:-17%;
            }

            .background-bubble:before {
                bottom:100%;
                left:80%;
                border-color: transparent #666 #666 transparent;
                border-width: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
            }

            .background-bubble:after {
                bottom:100%;
                left:82.5%;
                border-color: transparent #fff #fff transparent;
                border-width: 18px 18px 18px 18px;
```

My code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/aZ6bE/

Link to some wireframes/sample images of how I'd ideally like it to scale: http://ge.tt/2puJ7Hh1/v/0?c

Comment: Can you add an image of how you want it to look?

Comment: Do you mean something like this?? http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/kNKX4/19/

Comment: No, I am looking for the images to actually overlap quite a bit more. Per your request, I've added a set of pictures of what how I'd ideally like the objects to look. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe this could help http://jsfiddle.net/HGQ25/

Comment: When I compared the code, the only difference I found was the .foreground-bubble:before{} had its position changed from 13% to 50px. Was that what you intended or am i missing something?
    
Unfortunately, the problem of the blue foreground bubble moving above the white bubble when the browser is made larger (and subsequently too far down when the browser is made smaller) still persists. 

Additionally, the change to the foreground-bubble:before{}'s left position also makes it's tip become disconnected upon such browser resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the positioning I removed the `.background-bubble` `margin-bottom:-17%` and instead added `top:-100px` to `.foreground-bubble` since its `position:relative`.
I also gave the wrapping div a new class "bubbles" and added `margin-top:50px` to move it a bit further down so the tips don't collide with the text.

According the tips of the bubbles I changed:

- the size (`border-width`) of the bigger triangle
- percentage -> pixels
- (background-bubble) left -> right

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V4mF3/3/)

I would also suggest you combine some of the CSS into new classes to reduce the redundancy.
e.g the `border-width` and `bottom:100%` of the tips.

Comment: Vielen Dank Lukas! Du bist mein Held. :) This solves my problem and the tips definitely look better in pixels over percentages...I knew it looked a little wonkey. Bonus points for you!

Comment: I guess the two key takeaways were grouping the two bubbles into the “bubbles” class and working in pixels instead of percentages. Otherwise, is there a certain principle, lesson, or mode of operating which i should have used that would have led me to that?

Comment: Your recommendation to reduce redundancy seemed like wise feedback… I actually didn't know how to implement it at first b/c a) I hadn't before defined two classes/id's at once and b) when i tried to think about it, I got hung up on the idea of actually create "new classes" that would only refer to before/after pseudo elements if a certain condition, etc… then I thought, why can’t I just keep the old classifications and describe multiple classes at once…how do I do that?… oh, yeah, I’ve been looked at it all this time in the Twitter Bootstrap css! Worked like magic: http://jsfiddle.net/q4gLw/1/

Comment: Hmmm... as you said, grouping things that belong together is definitely a good idea in most cases. Also you have to be careful with using percentages in css. As you noticed, it can cause quite some problems. In most situations I would prefer px or em. Just use percentages if you really need it to adapt to window size (or the parent element). And if you do so, be sure to play around with the browser size to discover any weird layout bugs.